# Debug scenario for lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, ubuntu-18.04

As usual many things to do and no time to do it, so I need some suggestions.

This the scenario. AWS Lambda development based on SAM cli (aws cli/sam cli/docker/IntelliJ with AWS plugin) on Ubuntu 18.04
Developing a lambda function on node.js 12 - Javascript.

Everything is almost working perfectly.  I edit the function, run from IntelliJ, docker is executed with the lambda function, logs are happily popping up.
I say almost because I have a problem.

I create a text file in the function and is saved on /tmp/myTextFile.txt
I would like to be able to see the content of this file.
So I was wondering if exists a way to do it accessing the docker image.

I did try to "debug" the function rather than just execute it, putting a breakpoint after generating and saving the file.
I verified that the docker image remains open when the breakpoint is hit.

Then I did try to attach a terminal to the open docker image, no errors but also nothiing happens.
On a terminal I did open a terminal and :

- docker container ls
  I did see the docker image opened from the the local SAM development

Then :

- docker container attach "ID of the opened image"

and .. nothing.
There is a way to login and execute commands like "ls" or "cat" ?
In this way I could see if the file was generated and if is correct.

Thanks for any suggestion !

Steve

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but one approach that has been helpful when developing Lambda functions is to build them in a way that I can execute the code locally without deploying it, flushing out any functionality issues, then dealing with Lambda specifics on deploy. It saves on debug cycles, at least in Python, which I use often.

Comment: @petern He *is* running it locally, using SAM and Docker. The issue is not having access to the file system within the container.

Comment: I meant non-docker execution, some-what side-stepping the issue. But as you mentioned @jarmod, it's besides the original ask.

Comment: Thanks guys. Probably I can set up a non docker solution but I don't have time right now to do that (why we developers never have time to do what we need to do ???), I was wondering somebody else run on my problem.
In the end I was able to do a dirty trick and be able to retrieve the file from the function itself but I don't like when what used to be simple and direct become so complicated in name of "simplify things".